# Data frame Clip to shape in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

In ArcMap there is an option in data frame properties "Clip Options" and inside that drop down there is "Clip to Shape".
Apparently there seem to be no option in ArcGIS Pro. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a piece of ArcMap functionality that has not yet made it into ArcGIS Pro.

There are two ArcGIS Ideas that have been making the case for it to be added sooner rather than later:

- [Add Clip-To-Shape option to map frame in ArcGIS Pro](https://community.esri.com/ideas/12615-clip-map-to-shape-in-arcgis-pro) from @hornbydd
- [Clipping Map Frames to irregular shapes in ArcGIS Pro?](https://community.esri.com/thread/210313-clipping-map-frames-to-irregular-shapes-in-arcgis-pro) from me

On the first of these Esri staff member Kory Kramer has written:

> [barring any unforeseen hiccups we should see this in ArcGIS Pro 2.3 slated for early 2019](https://community.esri.com/ideas/12615-clip-map-to-shape-in-arcgis-pro#comment-66689)

In the meantime some requirements that the above would address can be met by creating a polygon feature class to use as a masking layer.